# ejabberd 15.07: no sasl log file anymore

Tags: ejabberd

I compiled ejabberd 15.07 (make install, using a prefix for destination).
I am under Linux Mint 16 (based on Ubuntu 13.10) with the distro's erlang package (version R16B01).

I also tested on Ubuntu 12.04 using Erlang OTP 18.0 (erlang compiled myself and ejabberd compiled using --with-erlang, distro's packages are not installed).

ejabberd works perfectly fine in both environments except that the `erlang.log` file is not created, basically no erlang SASL logs at all.

I upgraded from distro's ejabberd v2.1.10 where that file used to contain a bunch of supervisor logs or component crash/restarts.

Looking at ejabberdctl script, it actually does set the `sasl_error_logger` file like it always did in the past (e.g. in versions 2.x).

If I do

`gperrot@tristan ~/apps/ejabberd/sbin $ su -c 'erl -sasl sasl_error_logger \{file,\"/home/gperrot/apps/ejabberd/var/log/ejabberd/erlang.log\"\}'
Erlang R16B01 (erts-5.10.2) [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10] [kernel-poll:false]
Eshell V5.10.2  (abort with ^G)
1> application:start(sasl).
ok`

I can get a `erlang.log` file created with some content.

I used `bash -x ejabberdctl start` to check the command it uses:

`sh -c '/usr/bin/erl       -sname ejabberd@localhost       -noinput -detached       -pa /home/gperrot/apps/ejabberd/lib/ejabberd/ebin       -mnesia dir "\"/home/gperrot/apps/ejabberd/var/lib/ejabberd\""               -ejabberd log_rate_limit 100 log_rotate_size 10485760 log_rotate_count 1 log_rotate_date '\''""'\''       -s ejabberd       -sasl sasl_error_logger \{file,\"/home/gperrot/apps/ejabberd/var/log/ejabberd/erlang.log\"\}       +K true -smp auto +P 250000   start ""'`

File path is set properly, same user running, same file permissions.

I don't understand why I get no `erlang.log` file managed by ejabberd.

SASL is correctly started:

`gperrot@tristan ~/apps/ejabberd/sbin $ ejabberdctl debug
(ejabberd@localhost)1> application:start(sasl).
{error,{already_started,sasl}}`

And in `ejabberd.log` I also get

`2015-09-04 17:29:51.252 [info] <0.7.0> Application sasl started on node ejabberd@localhost`

But not `erlang.log` file.

Any idea why?

Comment: In latest installers, the errors are logged in a file name `error.log`. Did you try with ejabberdctl command-line tool ?

Comment: I do have an error.log being created when I use ejabberdctl start (empty because I guess i didn't trigger an error yet). Does that mean we don't have the SASL info logs anymore but only errors ? What confuses me is that the command line when I check ps aux also shows sasl_error_logger erlang.log.

Comment: There should be two files: ejabberd.log containing general logs and error.log being more generally related to SASL.

Comment: Ok I have those indeed. Yet the script references an additional unused file, erlang.log in the command line that is executed like I explained above. It might be a minor bug.

Comment: Thanks, we will have a look at this reference.